# How to solve this problem in Typescript 4.1.3 when you declare a variable ' : '

Tags: typescript

When you declare a variable example:

```
let names:string = "Yulio";
console.log(names);
```

The answer that it would give is the value of "names".

I got version Typescript 4.1.3 and Node JS 14.15.3 LTS

When I compile I get this error

[Error in Typescritpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk32H.png)

Why am I getting an error in ' : '? if the syntax is the correct when you declare a variable.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to run typescript directly, typescript needs to be compiled to JS to be runnable (after compilation the type annotation `: string` will be removed)

Comment: you probably also do not need to tell typescript, that the variable is a string, when you initialise it with a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something wrong with your configuration and you are trying to run the Typescript code directly that's why you get that syntax error.

When in doubt please do run your code here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

you'll see there's nothing wrong with it, so it has to bo a configuration issue.